# How to map my current RDD to a newly formatted one

Tags: python, pyspark

So right now my current rdd looks like this :

```
[(('DAI93865', 'FRO40251'), 1.0),
(('GRO85051', 'FRO40251'), 0.999176276771005),
(('GRO38636', 'FRO40251'), 0.9906542056074766),
(('ELE12951', 'FRO40251'), 0.9905660377358491),
```

I want to map it or flatMap it in a way that it ends up like this:

```
[(('DAI93865FRO40251'), 1.0),
(('GRO85051FRO40251'), 0.999176276771005),
(('GRO38636FRO40251'), 0.9906542056074766),
(('ELE12951FRO40251'), 0.9905660377358491),
```

So basically just combining the two terms into one.
How would I do this in pyspark?

What about this:

```
((('DAI23334', 'ELE92920'), 'DAI62779'), 1.0),
((('DAI31081', 'GRO85051'), 'FRO40251'), 1.0),
```

In this case, [0] [0] is:

```
(('DAI23334', 'ELE92920'), 'DAI62779')
```

I want to also combine these into one single string

Answer (score 0):

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    [
        (['a', 'b'], 'c'),
        (['d', 'e'], 'f')
    ]
)
rdd.collect()
[(['a', 'b'], 'c'), (['d', 'e'], 'f')]
```

You need to use `map` with your own logic:

```
rdd.map(lambda row: ((row[0][0]+row[0][1], ), row[1])).collect()
[(('ab',), 'c'), (('de',), 'f')]
```

Comment: hi I added another part that i have questions on